# Why is task resolution different in command-line vs dependsOn?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I am using the shadowJar plugin in my gradle build. Certain subprojects have a shadowJar task.

If I run `gradlew shadowJar` from the command line, the shadowJar tasks of all the sub-projects are executed. If on the other hand I have another task that `dependsOn shadowJar` and I run that, it only runs the shadowJar task on the root project.

What is the reason for this and how can I make my dependency use the same task resolution mechanism as the command line tool?

Answer (score 0):

That is perfectly fine. From command line it's gradle that handles this and resolves the tasks for all projects that are taking part in the current build - were included in included during [initialization](https://blog.softwaremill.com/my-task-whats-wrong-with-your-gradle-task-82312100c595) phase.

Whereas when you use `dependsOn` it depends on in which: `build.gradle` you expressed the dependency and also in which block e.g. `subprojects` or `allprojects`.